# How to add markers to map in windowsphone 8 by template?

Tags: windows-phone-8, maps, windows-phone, here-api

when i try to add userlocation markers to my map in windows phone 8 by template all points appear on the top left corner of map .
i am sure of that i have different locations this is my code :

```
            <maps:Map x:Name="myMap" Center="{Binding CenterPoint}" ZoomLevel="5">
            <toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllLocations}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Grid/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                            <toolkit:MapChildControl>
                                <toolkit:UserLocationMarker Background="Blue" Foreground="Green" GeoCoordinate="{Binding coordinate,Converter={StaticResource GeoCoordinateConverter}}"/>
                            </toolkit:MapChildControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                    </ItemsControl>
            </toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>

        </maps:Map>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately defining the binding in XAML doesn't work. *Don't known why. - Probably to do with the way the XAML is parsed and built at runtime.*

You can, however, set the binding in code and it will work.

This is from a working app:

```
<map:Map x:Name="TheMap">
    <toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
        <toolkit:MapItemsControl>
            <toolkit:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <toolkit:Pushpin GeoCoordinate="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PinToGeoCoordinateConverter}}"
                                        Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:MapItemsControl>
    </toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
</map:Map>
```

`Loaded` event for the page (in code behind)

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    this.Loaded -= OnLoaded;

    // Have to set up the ItemSource explicitly - unfortunately this doesn't work if set in XAML :(
    var children = MapExtensions.GetChildren(TheMap);
    var obj = children.FirstOrDefault(x => x is MapItemsControl) as MapItemsControl;

    obj.ItemsSource = ViewModel.Pins;
}
```

Comment: MapItemsControl seems to be not bindable. Your code behind just sets the ItemSource, it does not detect changes. I tried to manually do the binding instead, but MapItemsControl does not inherit FragmentsElement, therefore no GetBindingExpression() is available.

Comment: Still I solved it by setting an ObservableCollection and just changing the content.